# asp.net mvc 5 login failes with attachdbfilename when using both mysql provider and default one

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 with EF6. All my data is on a MySQL database, thats no problem. Then i implemented the Authentication that comes with the basic MVC template, which uses attachDB and stores the data to a .mdf file in App_Data. Here is the catch, sometimes it works, sometimes it does not. As i am near the finish with the project, i need it to be working 100% of the time. When i login, it throws the error of keyword no supported on attachdbfilename, and looking at the stack trace it uses the mysql provider, not the default ef.

error:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
          this line -->var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
          if (user != null)
          {
```

mysql entities context:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public partial class recycledbEntities
{

}
```

IdentityModels.cs

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(System.Data.Entity.DbConfiguration))]
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

web.config

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ORZWebApp-20140223060705.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ORZWebApp-20140223060705;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="recycledbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.RecycleModel.csdl|res://*/Models.RecycleModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.RecycleModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=MYSQLSERVER;user id=USER;password=PASSWORD;database=recycledb;characterset=utf8&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>

<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
 </entityFramework>
```